# How To Create Dynamic Array These Value Use Foreach?

Tags: php

```
$data_array = array(
array(
    'ID',
    'Name',
    'Designation ',
    'Message'
)
);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tbl_name");
while($data = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
{
array_push($data_array, array(
    $data->id,
    $data->name,
    $data->designation,
    $data->message
));
}
```

How can i create dynamic array for any sql table fields or data like in data array take fields value dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_query` functions are deprecated and have been removed in PHP 7. You should use `$mysqli->query` or PDO functions for database interactions

Instead of using `mysql_fetch_object`, you can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to fetch data as an associative array.